# Single regular expression for extracting different values

Tags: python, regex

I have some inputs like

```
ID= 5657A
ID=PID=FSGDVD
IDS=5645SD
```

I have created a regex i.e `IDS=[A-Za-z0-9]+|ID=[A-Za-z0-9]+|PID=[A-Za-z0-9]+`. But, in the case of `ID=PID=FSGDVD`, I want `PID=FSGDVD` as output.
My outputs must look like

```
ID= 5657A
PID=FSGDVD
IDS=5645SD
```

How to go for this problem?

Comment: is the space after `ID=` a typo? a simple workaround would be to add end of line anchor based on given samples

Comment: What about [`\w+=[^=\n]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/JkOdI9/1)?

Answer (score 3):

Add end of line anchor and use grouping and quantifiers to simplify the regex:

```
(?:IDS?|PID)=[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

- `IDS?` will match both `ID` and `IDS`
- `(?:IDS?|PID)` will match `ID` or `IDS` or `PID`

  - `(?:pattern)` is a non-capturing group, some functions like `re.split` and `re.findall` will change their behavior based on capture groups, thus non-capturing group is ideal whenever backreferences aren't needed
- `$` is end of line anchor, thus you'll get the match towards end of line instead of start of line

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/e9uvmC/1

In case your input can be something like `ID=PID=FSGDVD xyz` then you could use lookarounds:

```
(?:IDS?|PID)=[A-Za-z0-9]+\b(?!=)
```

Here `\b` will ensure to match all word characters after `=` sign and `(?!=)` is a negative lookahead assertion to avoid a match if there is `=` afterwards

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/e9uvmC/2

Answer (score 0):

Another one could be

```
[A-Z]+=\s*[^=]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KjMdgo/1/).